# Create Hexbin plot with pandas dataframe using index and columns names as x and y

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following pandas Dataframe `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, Decimal('nan')], [100, 10]], index=['y1', 'y2'], columns=['x1', 'x2'])

╔════╦═════╦═════╗
║    ║ x1  ║ x2  ║
╠════╬═════╬═════╣
║ y1 ║   1 ║ NAN ║
║ y2 ║ 100 ║ 10  ║
╚════╩═════╩═════╝
```

I would like to create a hex bin plot where the x-axis uses the column names `(x1, x2)` and the y-axis the indicies `(y1, y2)`. The Numbers in the Dataframe represent the counts, e.g. the higher the number the darker the color of the hex.
So ideally something like this:

```
df.plot.hexbin(x=df.columns, y=df.index.get_values())
```

Any chance to do this in a simple fashion?

Comment: Do you get error message ? Show it in question. And add some code which we could run to test it.

Comment: I am confused? The code I used was just an example to illustrate what I want.

Comment: SO is place to solve problem with existing code. You could at least create `df = DataFrame(...)` to get some example to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a dummy dataframe, `DF` :

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

np.random.seed(314)
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (10, 3)), columns=['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], 
                        index=['y{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 11)])
```

[image]

[`Melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) the `DF` to have a single column corresponding to the index, column and values respectively:

```
df = pd.melt(dummy_df.reset_index(), id_vars=['index'])
```

Take only the numerical portion of the strings to aid in plotting of the x and y axes of the hexbin plot.

```
df['index_int'] = df['index'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
df['variable_int'] = df['variable'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
```

***Plotting:***

Pass the values to `C` arg of the hexagonal bin plot which specifies the value at each (x, y) point:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
hex_ax = ax.hexbin(x=df['variable_int'], y=df['index_int'], C=df['value'], 
                   gridsize=10, cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
fig.colorbar(hex_ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, _: 'x{:.0f}'.format(x)))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: 'y{:.0f}'.format(y))) 
plt.xticks(np.unique(df['variable_int'].values))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note: If you use the hexbin built-in plot of the dataframe, the `xticks` and `xlabels` do not appear in the resulting plot and hence it's equivalent `matplotlib` hexbin method was called.[*see* [`GH issue`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10678)]